# Different errors like statement out of block, variable error showing in my macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to coding. I was trying to make a macro which searches through the charts in a sheet , searches if the chart has any data of Pfizer and then changing them in the chart to blue. So here, I am trying to search if datalabel has Pfizer and then changing the text to blue.
I tried using this code but did not work:-

```
Public Sub chartFormatting()

Dim CTRYname As String
Dim p As Integer
ivalue As String
Dim l As Integer
Dim rownum As Integer

For p = 1 To 13
    CTRYname = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Country lookup").Range("A1").Offset(p, 0).Value
    rownum = wkbCurr.Sheets(CTRYname).Range("AA25").End(xlDown).Row
    For s = 1 To rownum
        ivalue = wkbCurr.Sheets(CTRYname).Charts(1).SeriesCollection(1).Points(s).DataLabel.Text
        If InStr(ivalue, "Pfizer") <> 0 Then
            With ivalue
                With .Font
                    .Color = -65536
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                 End With
            End With
            wkbCurr.Sheets(CTRYname).Charts(1).SeriesCollection(1).Points(s).DataLabel.Text = ivalue
        End If
    Next s
Next p
End Sub
```

The variables have been declared else where too.
Now it is showing me a lot of errors. Please help and suggest a better way of formatting the text and lines in charts.

My main challenge is to format them only if Pfizer is there.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) regarding how and what to ask, because your question above isn't really the type of question that SO is about.

Comment: What errors do you get? Where are you variables declared? Better way of formatting is a subjective, opinion-based issue, so you won't get an objective answer to this question. Please ask concrete questions from now on and try to ask a single question at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of your issue here is navigating the Chart object hierarchy. I find a good way to figure it out is the use the macro recorder to record the action you want to code (colour a label in this case) abd examine to objects recorded.  You just need to ignore all the `Select` malarkey thae the recorder does and get to the core of the objects recorded.

I used this technique to refactor your code.  I also use intermediate objects(`sh`, `chrt` and `dl` in this case) to help break down the object model:

```
Public Sub chartFormatting()
    Dim CTRYname As String
    Dim p As Integer
    Dim ivalue As String
    Dim l As Integer
    Dim rownum As Integer
    Dim s As Long

    Dim dl As DataLabel
    Dim chrt As Chart
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    For p = 1 To 13
        CTRYname = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Country lookup").Range("A1").Offset(p, 0).Value
        Set sh = wkbCurr.Worksheets(CTRYname)
        rownum = sh.Range("AA25").End(xlDown).Row
        Set chrt = sh.ChartObjects(1).Chart
        For s = 1 To rownum
            With sh.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(s).DataLabel
                If InStr(.Text, "Pfizer") <> 0 Then
                    With .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor
                        .SchemeColor = 4
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                    End With
                End If
            End With
        Next s
    Next p
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot Chris. I also did something like this. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Chris, It is showing a run-time error 438. Object does not support this method or property. At this line :-  `With .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor`

Comment: What version of excel?  I tested this with 2010

Comment: Using Excel 2003. Any ways, i used colorindex = 5 and its working now, Thanks.